# in_category for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

how can I use the in_category for custom post types? here is my code.

```
<?php get_header('shop'); ?>
```

?>

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); global $_product; $_product = new jigoshop_product( $post->ID ); ?>

    <?php do_action('jigoshop_before_single_product', $post, $_product); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
         <div id="productssidebar">

        <?php if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar('Lesson Sidebar')) : else : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <?php do_action('jigoshop_before_single_product_summary', $post, $_product); ?>

        <div class="summary">
            <h1 id="pack">Lesson Pack</h1>
            <h1 class="product_title page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

            <?php do_action( 'jigoshop_template_single_summary', $post, $_product ); ?>

        </div>

        <!--IF POST BELONGS TO CATEGORY "PACKAGE"-->
        <div id ="pack-desc" style="margin-top: 293px;">
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <?php the_content();?>
        </div>
        <!--ELSE-->
        <?php do_action('jigoshop_after_single_product_summary', $post, $_product ); ?>
        <!--END IF-->

    </div>

    <?php do_action('jigoshop_after_single_product', $post, $_product); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

?>

thanks

Comment: Why can't you use in_category right there?

Comment: I tried sir, but the condition is not working 

`<?php 
  if (in_category('Lesson Pack')) { ?>
  
   <div id ="pack-desc" style="margin-top: 293px;">
   <h2>Description</h2>
   <?php the_content();?>
   </div>
  <?
  } 
  else 
  { 
   do_action('jigoshop_after_single_product_summary', $post, $_product );   
  }
  ?>`

please take a look sir, this product is in category  "uncategorize"
http://kjrias.com/store/metallica-enter-sandman/

while this product is in category 
"Lesson Pack"
http://kjrias.com/store/lesson1/

they are both using the "else"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`in_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) here is the correct function to use (it doesn't distinguish between post types).

The second argument accepted by `in_category` is the post ID or object - but in this case, can be omitted as we are using it inside the Loop.

The first argument is the Category ID (as an integer) or slug / name (as a string). Or alternatively an array of these. So make sure that 'Lesson Pack' is the name of the category (or else try using the slug, or the category ID).

---

#### Edit

As per comments, the plugin uses a custom taxonomy rather than the default category taxonomy. In that case, the function you should use is: [`has_term`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

```
 has_term('Lesson Pack', 'my-custom-taxonomy')
```

where the second argument is the name of the custom taxonomy.

Comment: Sir I already tried ID and Slug, and even using the `post_is_in_descendant_category` is also not working..  here is the edited code sir .. http://pastebin.com/MW2qazcL

Comment: Try listing the current post's category terms: `<?php global $post; var_dump(get_the_terms($post->ID,'category'));?>`. Are you using the default category taxonomy or a custom taxonomy?

Comment: That's a jigoshop's single-product.php template code and I'm pretty sure that they are using custom taxonomy.

Comment: Ah, in that case, see the edit :)